# Sequential Compactness of $I^\omega$ in the Standard Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

Give $I = [0,1]$ the standard subspace topology. Show the standard product topology on $X = I^\omega$ is sequentially compact. Is $ X$ compact?

I don't think $X$ is compact since it's open covers do not have finite subcovers, although I am not entirely sure if this is right or how to prove it.

I also don't know how to show that $I^\omega$ is sequentially compact. I don't understand how $I^\omega$ has a sequence of points, let alone how every sequence of points of $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Do you mean $\omega$ instead of $w$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ is compact by the [Tikhonov product theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem): it’s a product of compact spaces.

There are several ways to show that $X$ is sequentially compact. I’ll sketch two of them, leaving a number of details for you.

One is to show that $X$ is metrizable, and then use the fact that sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness in metric spaces. You can show that $X$ is metrizable by showing that the function $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ defined by

$$d(x,y)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n}\;,$$

where $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, is a metric on $X$ that generates the product topology.

You can also show it directly. Let $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $X$. Each of the points $x^{(n)}$ is itself a sequence of points of $I$; say $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$. Arranging the sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ vertically, we have the following picture:

$$\begin{align*}
x^{(0)}&=\left\langle x_0^{(0)},x_1^{(0)},x_2^{(0)},x_3^{(0)},\ldots\right\rangle\\
x^{(1)}&=\left\langle x_0^{(1)},x_1^{(1)},x_2^{(1)},x_3^{(1)},\ldots\right\rangle\\
x^{(2)}&=\left\langle x_0^{(2)},x_1^{(2)},x_2^{(2)},x_3^{(2)},\ldots\right\rangle\\
x^{(3)}&=\left\langle x_0^{(3)},x_1^{(3)},x_2^{(3)},x_3^{(3)},\ldots\right\rangle\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

We want to show that $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence that converges in $X$. Look at the first column of $(1)$ and think of it as the sequence $\langle x_0^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. This is a sequence in $I$, so it has a convergent subsequence. That means that there is an infinite $N_0\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that the subsequence $\langle x_0^{(n)}:n\in N_0\rangle$ converges to some $x_0\in I$.

Now look at the corresponding subsequence of the second column, $\langle x_1^{(n)}:n\in N_0\rangle$; this is another sequence in $I$, so it has a convergent subsequence. Thus, there is an infinite $N_1\subseteq N_0$ such that $\langle x_1^{(n)}:n\in N_1\rangle$ converges to some $x_1\in I$.

Continuing in this manner, we can construct an infinite sequence $\langle N_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ and a sequence $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $I$ in such a way that $N_0\supseteq N_1\supseteq N_2\supseteq\ldots$, and $\langle x_k^{(n)}:n\in N_k\rangle$ converges to $x_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.

Now let $n_0=\min N_0$, and for each $k\in\Bbb N$ let

$$n_{k+1}=\min\{\ell\in N_{k+1}:\ell>n_k\}\;;$$

then prove that the subsequence $\langle x^{(n_k)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of the original sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to the point $x\in X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is there a 2^n in the denominator of the distance function?

Comment: @emseon: To make the series converge.